# Re-write file without EXIF data in Android Studio

Tags: apache-commons, metadata-extractor, apache-commons-imaging

I want the java code or library to write the minimal EXIF data back to IMAGE files (JPG, GIF, PNG, etc.) in Android Studio. The EXIFREWRITER is not working. Also, METADATAEXTRACTOR is extracting but not re-writing back to the file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me for converting all extensions (HEIC, GIF, CR2, PNG etc.):

```
 FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(new File(inputFilePath));
    Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(inStream);
    Bitmap picBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(inputFilePath);
    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(copiedFile));
    picBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
    for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
        for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {
            System.out.println("Tag :" + tag);
        }
    }
```